# How to loop falling object in flash AS3 once it has hit bottom of the scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is the code i have got so far for a single falling object. The 'DangerIN' is the instance name for the object that is falling down. The class is named 'Danger'. So how can i make it loop so it falls continuously and when it reaches certain y value it will remove it self. Also i want more than one(abount 5) objects falling down at once.

```
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 550;
DangerIN.x = randomX;
DangerIN.y = 96;

var speed:Number = Math.random()*10;

DangerIN.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);

function moveDown(e:Event):void {
    e.target.y += speed; 

    if(e.target.y >= 610) {
        DangerIN.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some more of your code. Where / how do you create `DangerIn`?

Comment: Danger is a movieclip and DangerIN is the instance name of that movie clip. That is all the code i have for the falling object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. But to do that, you first need an Array of falling stuff, and then you need to reposition your `e.target` to the top once it's below your threshold.

```
function moveDown(e:Event):void {
    e.target.y += speed;
    if (e.target.y >= 610) {
        // reposition
        e.target.x=math.random()*550;
        e.target.y=96;
    }
}
```

Assign this function to every object you want to fall down, reach bottom and reappear back up.

Comment: How does that remove the object? _when it reaches certain y value it will remove it self_

Comment: @putvande He actually seeks for infinite loop, as he mentioned it alongside "removal", this makes it for infinite loop.

Comment: @ParthChaudhari If this is what you are seeking, please click the "tick" symbol on the left of the answer, so telling others it's the right one.

Answer (score 0):

To remove itself you can add a following line after the removeEventListener():

```
parent.removeChild(this);
```

But it's not pretty and you probably should to it the right way:

Store all the Danger objects in the array, in the Danger class create a function like go(), moveDown() or something:

```
public function go():void
{
    y+= speed;
}
```

and in the class where you create the Danger objects make a loop like this:

```
private function loop():void
{
    for (var i:int = dangerObjArray.lenght - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      dangerObjArray[i].go();

      if (dangerObjArray[i].y >= maxY)
         dangerObjArray.splice(i , 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new in action script 3 so i dont know how to make an array.